# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name when running JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

I made a maven spring-boot project using Spring Initializr and added the basic dependencies like starter-web, tom-cat-jasper, dev-tools and etc.. then imported it in Eclipse.

I then added a new external JAR in my local repository that is not from maven repository using

```
mvn install:install-file
```

and added the new dependendcy in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.domain.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>resourceName</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this external JAR has a .properties that's need to be added in order for it to connect to a database. I put this .properties file in **src/main/resources** and tested the methods in the external JAR and it works as intended in the Eclipse IDE.

After this I run the project as Maven build with goals: `clean install` so that it can be run as an executable JAR.

Then I run the JAR with `start java -jar` using a .bat file everything is working but whenever I used the methods from the external JAR via GET/POST request it gives the error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resourceName, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1581) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at com.domain.project.vitality.VitalityInfo.VitalityInfoDetails(VitalityInfo.java:28) ~[resourceName-1.jar!/:?]
```

This is the name of the external JAR: resourceName.jar and the required properties file: resourceName.properties.

I also encountered this error if I rename or removed the required .properties file in **src/main/resources** in Eclipse IDE.

If I run the project only in Eclipse IDE and access the said external JAR methods via GET/POST request it gives the usual JDBC SQL error.

How do I fix this whenver I build using maven any help is very much appreciated?

EDIT: This is the result from `jar tf` of executable JAR when using maven build.

```
BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties
BOOT-INF/classes/resourceName.properties
BOOT-INF/classes/log4j2-spring.xml
```

EDIT: Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was rather simple.
In my case the external JAR has this in its implementation

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resourceName");
```

I changed this into

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
```

And simply renamed resourceName.properties file into application.properties or just copy the content from resourceName.properties into your application.properties or any property file that spring-boot is able to read.